# net-snmp tutorial snmpset failed

Tags: net-snmp

I am trying to make net-snmp to support my own MIB, but I failed. I was following the instructions here:
http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_MIB_Module.

Then I think maybe I could just use the example MIB file and .c and .h file to test if the example works. Again, by following the tutorials in the above link, I get this to work:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public localhost NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentModuleObject.0
```

and I got this:

`NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentModuleObject.0 = INTEGER: 1` (which looks good).

But then I try to test snmpset like this:

`snmpset -v 2c -c public localhost NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentModuleObject.0 i 5`

or

```
snmpset -v 2c -c public localhost NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentModuleObject.0 = 5
```

or

```
snmpset -v 2c -c public localhost NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentModuleObject.0 INTEGER 5
```

and I got the following error:

```
Error in packet.
Reason: wrongLength (The set value has an illegal length from what the agent expects)
Failed object: NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentModuleObject.0
```

Please help me understand where did I do wrong. All the files are from the tutorial and I did not
change anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tell how you set your parameter for your customOid using net-snmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are programming on a 64bit target [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/net-snmp/+bug/587828) can help you

Comment: Yes, this is because of I was running it on a 64bit machine. After I switch to a 32bit machine, I can set and get without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep running on a 64bit machine you can change the variable from int to long:

`static int  nstAgentModuleObject = 1;`   ==>   `static long .....` 
`netsnmp_register_int_instance(....)` ==> `netsnmp_register_long_instance(....)`